The PDF attachment is absent when sending an email with an RSVP calendar format
Can someone assist in resolving the issue where the PDF attachment is missing when creating an RSVP calendar event email with an additional PDF attachment in .NET Framework
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:India Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN="<name>";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:<mail>
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20240410T114929Z
DESCRIPTION:<description>
DTEND;TZID="India Standard Time":20240409T160000
DTSTAMP:20240409T091546Z
DTSTART;TZID="India Standard Time":20240409T153000
LAST-MODIFIED:20240410T114929Z
LOCATION:Microsoft Teams Meeting
ORGANIZER;CN="<name>":mailto:<mail>
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:<summary>
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:<UID>
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<htmldata>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-APPTLASTSEQUENCE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

